# Mongoose 'model is not a constructor' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

So this seems like a fairly popular error. And after seeing all the previous questions, I am posting this as they don't solve my problem. Most popular errors were using `module.export` instead of `module.exports` and calling a new instance of the schema instead of the model. I am making none of these mistakes. Here's the code.

```js
const db = require('mongoose');

db.Promise = global.Promise;

db.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/mydb').then(
    () => {console.log('Connection to database established')}
).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

module.exports = {db};
```

```js
const {db} = require('./dbconf');

// Schema for users
let UserSchema = new db.Schema({
    username : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        trim : true,
        min : 1,
        unique: true
    },
    password : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        trim : true,
        min : 8
    },
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        trim : true,
        min : 1
    },
    email : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        trim : true,
        min : 1,
        unique : true
    }
});

const User = db.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = {User};
```

```js
const {User} = require('../db/models');

let user = new User({
    username : username,
    password : password,
    name : name,
    email : email
});
```

And here at `let user = new User({` I get `TypeError: User is not a constructor`

Comment: what does `console.log(User)` say?

Comment: @OlivierKrull It says : Model { User }

Comment: What version of Mongoose? I don't see anything immediately wrong.

Comment: @DaveNewton Version `5.9.10`. Btw this code used to run fine 1 year ago with version `5.4.1` when I used it in this project which I made while I was a beginner (https://github.com/zaygozi/zagan-user-management). When I compare the code, it looks similar. I guess I'll try using the older version.

Comment: Nah the error persists with `5.4.1`. I don't understand why it worked then but not now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember having a similar issue with webpack/typescript.

Try exporting the module like

```
module.exports.User = User;
```

and import the entire db index file without using destructor...just to see if it makes a difference.

```
const models = require('../db/models');
const user = new models.User(...);
```

In my case it was something that webpack did that messed up the imports.

Quick Edit:
I created the same setup as you have(with the latest mongoose).

```
// models file
const userSchema = new Schema({
    message: { type: String, maxlength: 5000 }
});
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports.User = User;

// another file
const { User } = require('./testmodels.js');
console.log('==>', User  );

will log out 
==> function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
      model.hooks.execPreSync('createModel', doc);
      if (!(this instanceof model)) {
        return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
      }
      const discriminatorKey = model.schema.options.discriminatorKey;
      if (model.discriminators == null || doc == null || doc[discriminatorKey] == null) {
        Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
        return;
      }
      // If discriminator key is set, use the discriminator instead (gh-7586)
      const Discriminator = model.discriminators[doc[discriminatorKey]] ||
        getDiscriminatorByValue(model, doc[discriminatorKey]);
      if (Discriminator != null) {
        return new Discriminator(doc, fields, skipId);
      }
      // Otherwise, just use the top-level model
      Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
    }
```

Just out of curiosity, what happens if you try to call the constructor like this.

```
let user = new User.User({
    username : username,
    password : password,
    name : name,
    email : email
});
```

Another update: 
I tried out your example code and it works for me( I also tested with the latest Mongo version and it still worked ).
The only thing I had to change in your example was the module exports line where you only exported MK and not the User model.

```
module.exports = {User, SigningKey, MK};
```

[image]

Comment: Nah man, now the error is `models.User is not a constructor`. I wanted this to work as I have also solved some problems in the past in this way. I guess, not today.

Comment: @Endemic Updated my post.

Comment: Rainer thanks for trying to emulate the code for my sake. Calling the constructor in that way just throws the error : `Cannot find property User of undefined`. I literally can't understand whats wrong! If you have the time, can you look at the complete code and see if something catches your eye. Appreciate all your help. Here's the complete code : https://github.com/zaygozi/zum-v2

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid. I created those 3 models at different times, so I created 3 module.exports without a second thought. All I had to do was combine them into 1. Never realized that causes such a problem. Thank you so much.